# Edit conf file in python

Tags: python, file, jboss, configuration-files

I want to edit a conf file like below in python:

```
# The username who should own the process.
USER_NAME=root

#The amount of time to wait for startup
# STARTUP_WAIT=30
```

I am thinking of replacing lines, but for some reason, it's not working.

```
def replaceAll(file,searchExp,replaceExp):
    for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=1):
        if searchExp in line:
            line = line.replace(searchExp,replaceExp)
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Is there any way to do this, please help.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that shows **what's** not working? We don't know what is or isn't working.

Comment: @aryamccarthy If I am making a call like replaceAll(file,"USER_NAME=","USER_NAME=root"), the output will be USER_NAME=rootroot

Comment: That's because you're replacing only `"USER_NAME="` with `"USER_NAME=root"`. You don't do anything about the `root` that's still on the line.

Comment: Also, can you provide a more complete sample of your .ini file?

Comment: Read about https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html